# Issues with NSInvalidArgumentExceptionn NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: swift, nskeyedarchiver

I'm trying to create an object and save it via the NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject method (I know this is deprecated but this is for school work) but the app is crashing as soon as I attempt to save. I've narrowed the issue to the line "let isSuccessfulSave".

This is for an iOS app, I'm running it in the iOS simulator currently running iOS 12.2, I've attempted to fully uninstall the app and reinstall it (thinking old save attempts where maybe the issue) but the issue remains the same.

Save function:

```
@IBAction func saveImage(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.myImageView.image == nil{
        return
    }

    if nameTextField.text == ""{
        return
    }


    let fileName = nameTextField.text ?? ""
    let photo = self.myImageView.image!
    let thisFile = MyFile(name: fileName, photo: photo, fileType: MyFile.FileType.drawing)//Last argument is an enum declared in the MyFile class
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(thisFile!, toFile: MyFile.ArchiveURL.path)//Last argument is declared as static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("myFiles") in the MyFile class
    if isSuccessfulSave{
        os_log("Drawing successfully saved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    } else {
        os_log("Failed to save drawing", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
    }


}
```

Init being used:

```
init?(name: String, photo: UIImage, fileType: FileType){
    guard !name.isEmpty else{
        return nil
    }

    self.name = name
    self.photo = photo
    self.fileType = fileType

}
```

Error log is the following:

```
2019-07-15 13:25:55.935796-0700 AppleNotes[2578:45797] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
2019-07-15 13:26:01.035761-0700 AppleNotes[2578:45797] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/gabriel/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7851257A-19F9-42EA-9E80-318C61C15ADD/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-07-15 13:26:01.040518-0700 AppleNotes[2578:45797] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
/Users/gabriel/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7851257A-19F9-42EA-9E80-318C61C15ADD/data/Containers/Data/Application/B06CD57F-2FED-4EA2-B802-7942065E9B60/Documents/myFiles
2019-07-15 13:26:04.923588-0700 AppleNotes[2578:45797] -[__SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000184dbc0
2019-07-15 13:26:04.935456-0700 AppleNotes[2578:45797] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000184dbc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa676fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ac1aac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa85ab4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa6c443 ___forwarding___ + 1443
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa6e238 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Foundation                          0x000000010a6aa3d0 _encodeObject + 1230
6   AppleNotes                          0x000000010a1d59db $s10AppleNotes6MyFileC6encode4withySo7NSCoderC_tF + 1259
7   AppleNotes                          0x000000010a1d5afc $s10AppleNotes6MyFileC6encode4withySo7NSCoderC_tFTo + 60
8   Foundation                          0x000000010a6aa3d0 _encodeObject + 1230
9   Foundation                          0x000000010a6a9588 +[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:toFile:] + 214
10  AppleNotes                          0x000000010a1d1b5b $s10AppleNotes11PaintWindowC9saveImageyyypF + 2763
11  AppleNotes                          0x000000010a1d1f7c $s10AppleNotes11PaintWindowC9saveImageyyypFTo + 76
12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110bb3204 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
13  UIKitCore                           0x000000011031d963 __45-[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:]_block_invoke + 154
14  UIKitCore                           0x000000011031d89c -[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:] + 152
15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110bb3204 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110608c19 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
17  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110608f36 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
18  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110607eec -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 583
19  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110bebeee -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2547
20  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110bed5d2 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4079
21  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110bcbd16 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
22  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110c9c293 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3232
23  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110c9ebb9 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5911
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9cebe1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9ce463 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9c8b1f __CFRunLoopRun + 1231
27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9c8302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
28  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010d7fc2fe GSEventRunModal + 65
29  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110bb1ba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
30  AppleNotes                          0x000000010a1cbecb main + 75
31  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001132d7541 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: `MyFile` must be a class which inherits from `NSObject`. It must adopt the `NSCoding` protocol and it must implement the two required protocol methods `init(coder` and `encodeWithCoder`.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for the quick response! I've already verified that and indeed the class  inherits from NSObject and adopts  NSCoding `class MyFile: NSObject, NSCoding` it also implements both `func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)` and `required convenience init?(coder aCoder: NSCoder)`

Comment: Then the reason is the enum which cannot be exposed to Objective-C

Comment: I guess I'll change that argument to string and test it out, I'll reply my findings, thanks!

Comment: Alternatively add a computed property which maps the enum cases to something NSCoding compatible or make the enum `RawRepresentable`.

Comment: @vadian that was the issue, thanks! Any background on this? It's driven me nuts for like the past hour or so, does Objective-C just straight up not support enum datatypes?

Comment: Objective-C does not support Swift enums **without** raw values as all ObjC enums are based on integer raw values.

Comment: Aight, that's good to know, thanks for the help m8!